# Does roxygen2 work for R scripts in data-raw?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I am using RStudio to create a package for a piece of data analysis I'm doing. To put my raw data into the package, I'm using `devtools::use_data_raw()` as per [this article](http://www.davekleinschmidt.com/r-packages/).

I have a script `load-raw-data.R` that loads the raw data and assembles it into a dataframe, then calls `devtools::use_data()` on this dataframe to add it to the package. `load-raw-data.R` is in `/data-raw` not `/R`, as per the article. I've added documentation to the functions in this script via a `roxygen2` skeleton, however when I build the documentation the `.Rd` files for these functions are not built. I presume this is because roxygen2 is only looking in `/R`. Is there a way to tell `roxygen2` to look in `/data-raw` as well? Or have I misunderstood something along the way?

Update: following @phil's suggestion

@phil - thanks - I tried this for one of the functions (`load_data_files`) in the `load-raw-data.R` script (see below for the documentation added to R/data.R), but on rebuilding the package I get an error: `'load_data_files' is not an exported object from 'namespace:clahrcnwlhf'`. I have included the `@export` tag in the documentation in `R/data.R`. Any thoughts on how I might resolve this?

```
`# This script loads the individual component files of the raw dataset
# and stitches them together, saving the result as an .RData file

#' load_data_files
#'
#' load_data_files loads in a set of Excel files as dataframes
#'
#' @param fl list of paths of the files to be loaded
#'
#' @return A list of dataframes, one for each of the file paths in fl.
#' @export
"load_data_files"`
```

Comment: A bit late, but if you place your documentation in `R/data.R` then `roxygen` will pick it up and build your documentation from there

Comment: @phil - thanks - I tried this for one of the functions (`load_data_files`) in the `load-raw-data.R` script, but on rebuilding the package I get an error: `'load_data_files' is not an exported object from 'namespace:clahrcnwlhf'`. I have included the `@export` tag in the documentation in `R/data.R`. Any thoughts on how I might resolve this?

Comment: Won't help with getting an answer here, but I always find it worth some appreciation when people do the right thing and delete off topic content ;-)

Comment: Likewise, appreciate the guidance, and civility in the manner it is delivered, thanks!